# While condition not met, but still continuing

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I wrote a code for inputting integers as strings and wanted to end the loop when I am inputting a "0". I tried it and it didn't work. I am inputting a zero, it is printing "Next", it is printing the zero means that it is saving the zero in the "inputting" variable, but the loop is still continuing.

The code(Without Main and class):

```
import java.util.*;

String inputting = "";
            
       while(inputting != "0")
       {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         inputting = scan.next();
         System.out.println("Next");
         System.out.println(inputting);
       }
```

What could be the reason? How can I maybe improve it that the loop stops continuing?

Thanks

I tried to input as many characters as possible, but when a zero comes, it should stop. It didn't stop.

Comment: Do not compare strings with `==` or `!=`. Use `equals()` or `!equals()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is creating a new Scanner object every iteration neccessary?
Also try use

```
inputting.equals("0")
```

Comment: I don't know if it would work then. I want an input request every time